# CakePHP - Using Model::read() on a model with no table

Tags: cakephp, model

I have a model with `$useTable = false` and a custom `$schema` defined.

I am trying to keep everything as integral to the framework as possible, by using standard model methods, even though there is no table.  So, for example, I am using `Model::save()` to update the `$data` array of the model.

However, from a controller I am trying to use `Model::read()`, but it is failing I think because `read()` doesn't have an ID in the model.  Is there any way to simulate IDs in the model without a table?  I know I can access the data I want through `$this->Model->data['Model']['field']` but I feel that is not good practice.

Comment: so where is $data stored? If you are using save() and read(), you probably need a table to store data.

Comment: If you want to "read" data, just read it from the model that actually has the data/table.  $this-ActualDataModel->read()    Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read() is for when you're retrieving data based on the primary key, or id.

If you're trying to read data from the underlying datasource (whatever that may be) but there's no primary key, then perhaps find('first', ...) is what you might want.

If you do have a primary key, but it's not called 'id' (perhaps 'field'), then assign `var $primaryKey = 'field';` in the model, and you should be fine to use read, based on that field data.

Incidentally, what is the underlying data source?